# Can a 2D universe be closed?

Tags: spacetime, metric-tensor, curvature, spacetime-dimensions, topology

Consider a universe as a curved 1D line looped onto itself. The second dimension is time. On one hand, this line is easy to visualize as a circle embedded in a flat 2D plane. However, there is only one spatial dimension, so this 2D plane is not real. On the other hand, a 1D space has no intrinsic curvature, but without a curvature, how can this space be looped in a circle? Can anyone please clarify if a 2D universe with the metric signature of (1,1) can be closed and if so how would it be described mathematically?

Comment: Open/closed is a topological concept, that is, independent of the metric or signature. You are essentially asking whether there are two-dimensional closed manifolds (and the answer is quite trivially *yes*).

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform Hmm... Has I managed to ask such a simple question in such a way that it is unclear? Obviously I did not imply any dependence of topology on the metric signature. You pretty much can ignore time in my question, which becomes about space only. Now, space here is one-dimensional, so it is not a two-dimensional closed manifold, which would have an intrinsic curvature. In contrast, a one-dimensional manifold does not have an intrinsic curvature. We can imagine it closed by embedding, but what if the embedding space does not exist? Can a 1D manifold still be closed?

Comment: Again, open/closed is a *topological* concept. It has nothing to do with the *geometry* of the manifold. It is independent of the curvature, or any other metric notion. Yes: you can have a 1D closed manifold (e.g., the circle).

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform Alright, let me put it this way (there is a reason I'm asking this on the physics site instead of math). If normally space is curved by gravity and with enough gravity can be curved enough to be looped onto itself and closed, this works, because gravity creates a local intrinsic curvature that adds up globally to make the space closed. With no intrinsic curvature in 1D, gravity is not possible. There is nothing to add up globally to make the space closed. Then what could cause this space to be closed? The initial conditions perhaps?

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform Also, regarding "a 1D closed manifold (e.g., the circle)", I think, "circle" is a 2D concept. We can say, a circle is a 1D manifold embedded in a 2D plane. This requires the second dimension to exist, but it does not exist in my question. I understand a 1D manifold can conceptually be looped to have a certain round trip length, but its "shape" (e.g. "circle") would be a meaningless concept, would it not?

Comment: @safesphere: 'circle' can be defined without any embeddings. For example, 'fractional part' function induces circular topology on a real line with $x \sim \mathop{\mathrm{frac}} (x)$ equivalence  without any appeal to higher dimensions. Your thinking about 2D (or 3D) embedding is an artifact of intuition formed with a visualization. An example of concept that does require embedding into higher dimension is a 'winding number'.

Comment: @safesphere: Although, upon reflection, I do see a point of your question (more from your comments than the question as it is now): whether the topology of spacetime is a dynamic variable. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Safesphere, in spite of knowing no geometry perhaps I get what you mean. If I will be confined in the 1D loop I would have no means to check for its curvature by using a ruler. Is this that you mean? I mean for a sphere I can draw circles or triangle on it and find that Euclide does not hold. What about a 1D? Is there any mathematical geometrical tool equivalent to put a mark , move past it and arriving at it again? In such a sense we will be sure that the space is sort of flat but close on itself. Ignore if I have completely misunderstood.

Comment: @Alchimista Yes, you got it right. My question is, if the 1D space is flat, what could cause it to be looped? Not gravity, cause there's no gravity in a flat space. Perhaps just the initial conditions meaning that it just was created this way in the first place. I don't know if my question is too trivial or too hard, but no answer so far.

Comment: I don't know but there should be a mathematical way to express that there is a loop. Perhaps saying is 1D  but close . However I do not seet how to find out from itself without marking a point and actually moving along the full loop.....

Comment: @Alchimista Correct provided the loop can be tested by sending a ray of light instead of personally traveling. However, this space can also be expanding and so the light may never come back around. Then how do we distinguish between an open and closed universes? There would seem to be no testable differences.

Comment: Couldn't up have your space dimension be a circle, and you time dimension be the real line?

Comment: @PyRulez This is a (1,1) universe with only one spatial dimension. A circle is a spatial object embedded in a 2D plane. Because there is no second embedding spatial dimension in this universe, and a 1D space does not have an intrinsic curvature, the shape of this space (e.g. "circle") has no meaning. All we can say is that this space may be closed (looped onto itself) or not (infinite). However, if it also is expanding, then it may be hard or impossible to know if it is closed or open, because a round trip may be impossible even for the light. Time, yes, is straight and rather irrelevant here.

Comment: @safesphere I mean a topological circle, which is 1 dimensional.

Comment: @PyRulez What is a 1D "topological circle" and how is it different from, say, a 1D "topological square"? I would appreciate if you provide a definition (without the use of embedding in non-existing dimensions). Thanks!

Comment: @safesphere it's the same as 1D topological square. In particular, it's any space that is homeomorphic to [0,1]/{0,1} (the unit internal where the endpoints are considered the same point). It's topological dimension is 1.

Comment: @PyRulez Understood. This is the same as what I described above by saying that shape has no meaning, only the length of the roundtrip does.  However, if this space is expanding, then this length may be impossible to measure and it may become meaningless as well. This is all cool, but the essence of my question is physics or deeper math. What could cause this space to exist? Gravity can't bend it, then what wouod make it closed? Math tends to assume the given, like a specific topology. Assume nothing. What could cause this topology? There seems to be no answer other than the initial conditions.

Comment: @safesphere I'm pretty sure a 1D universe is physically impossible. You'll have to specify what laws of physics you want to change to make it possible.

Comment: In the realm of pure math, something is always given and certain things logically follow from it. In your comment, you assume that the space topology is given and then you make some conclusions based on that. However, no specific topology is given in this case. The topology here is a logical consequence. My question is, what is it a logical consequence of? What could be the cause of such a topology to emerge mathematically? For example, in 2D or 3D, we could suggest, it is the intrinsic curvature. Note here that the topology is not given, but emerges as a result of the intrinsic curvature.

Comment: @A.V.S. "*'fractional part' function induces circular topology on a real line with $x\sim frac⁡(x)$ equivalence without any appeal to higher dimensions.*" - I see, thank you! Essentially a 1-torus. "*whether the topology of spacetime is a dynamic variable. Is that what you mean?*" - Another good point, but not really. What I rather mean is that "topology" in the physical reality would seem to be a consequence of geometry (dynamic or not), a sort of an evolution from realistic initial conditions. It is unclear how a 1-torus topology in my question can evolve from anything physically meaningful.